# Can't get Images appear next to each other in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I can't get my images to appear next to each other (even with display:inline-block) what can I do?

HTML & CSS code:

```css
.emb-web-links {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.icons {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="emb-web-links" style="width: 26px;display:inline-block">
  <a style="text-decoration:     underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://www.facebook.com/ifarmaciascom/?fref=ts" class="icons">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i8.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/facebook.png" target="_blank" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://twitter.com/ifarmaciaspt" class="icons">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i9.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/twitter.png" target="balnk" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://vimeo.com/user22709514/videos/">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i10.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/youtube.png" target="_blank" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color:  #fff;" href="https://pt.linkedin.com/company/ifarmacias-com" target="_blank">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i3.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/linkedin.png" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO ... please include your detailed question on the question itself not just in the title to be more clear

Comment: Probably because the parent is limited to 26px?

Comment: My mistake reading the code, I see absolute positioning and I think it's with the icons, not the parent. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline CSS width

```css
.emb-web-links {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.icons {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="emb-web-links">
  <a style="text-decoration:     underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://www.facebook.com/ifarmaciascom/?fref=ts" class="icons">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i8.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/facebook.png" target="_blank" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://twitter.com/ifarmaciaspt" class="icons">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i9.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/twitter.png" target="balnk" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color: #fff;" href="https://vimeo.com/user22709514/videos/">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i10.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/youtube.png" target="_blank" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>

  <a style="text-decoration: underline;transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in;color:  #fff;" href="https://pt.linkedin.com/company/ifarmacias-com" target="_blank">
    <img style="border: 0;" src="https://i3.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/13-the-blueprint-3/images/linkedin.png" width="26" height="26" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the inline style `width: 26px;` from `.emb-web-links`.

You're constraining the width/area in which your icons can line up.

Ideally you wouldn't want to use inline CSS styles. Though I'm assuming that this code isn't final and that you're eventually going to move the inline CSS to their associated `.emb-web-links` and `.icons` classes.